# Thinking about the efficiency of MySQL+PHP, which is better?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I think of creating an administrative panel where all the inputs/textareas/selects that run the 'site' are created by MySQL.

What's better, create a row for each input/textarea/select referring to a page, or put the information of all inputs/textareas/selects each page in a single field and use the php explode in order to use the data ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise to use case 1. If you will need to change PHP to some another technology (i.e. Java or Python), then it may have no "unserialize" function.
Also, it is easier to read data if you will need to analyse it manually.

Comment: yes. also: don't worry about performance. mysql will be much quicker returning a few more rows than php fiddling apart your string. that is what a rdbms is meant to do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 -- you're going to be storing that information in a relational database, so you may as well get the advantages that offers (for querying, udpating etc.) It will allow you to more easily manage your fields and change attributes of those fields.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to say Case 1 is better - keeps data better organized. Also, SQL is FAST, much faster than PHP, anyway, so if there is one less task for PHP to do (i.e. explode), the better.

Finally - it will be so much easier to maintain case 1. If you wanted to update the name of a field of a certain form, for example, you can...do just that, update only the name of that field. Otherwise you'll have to potentially do a find and replace, which may mean having to select, read, find, replace, update, a much more cumbersome operation.

Just my opinion, but I would go with case 1.